# How to place labels at the boundary of the current map extent

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling

I have a layer of reference grid lines on top of several map layers. The grid lines should be labeled with coordinate values: vertical grid lines with x-values and horizontal lines with y-values. The label position should be at the border of the current mapcanvas extent.

I was unable to write an expression which uses mapCanvas().extent() due to illegal characters (the dot) . Geometry properties only will not return these coordinates.

My idea so far: creating point features at the intersection of grid lines and map extent triggered by extentChanged event, and labeling these points.

Has somebody a better idea?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the print composer?

Comment: I want this in the map view. I  know the grid as decoration, but I want more flexibility concerning the labeling. Then this Feature might be used for labeling other objects as well, eg streets labeled with the next City lying outside the map.

Comment: @Detlev u want the labeling to appear **only** on the border of the MapCanvas and not at every lines crossings ?

Comment: @snaileater yes, only at the border of the map canvas. I need more control over the reference grid and the labels at the border, the

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into the Maplex Label Engine? It's a pretty powerful labeling option that might be suited for your needs. It comes with all ArcMap versions over 10.0 IIRC.

Comment: the question is qgis/pyqgis related obviously ...